# How to use inline css in react app without 'unsafe inline' for style-src in Content-Security-Policy?

Tags: reactjs, content-security-policy

I am using content-security-policy for the react application. Where some of the libraries creates inline styles while generating charts.
Also we have our own inline styles at some places which generated based on data.

Now issue is Content-Security-Policy we have unsafe-inline which allowing inline styles where we want to remove 'unsafe-inline' from 'style-src'. After removing 'style-src' application does not work properly as inline styles are blocked.

How we can remove unsafe-inline without impact on application.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you find any solution for that?
I tried searching a lot and couldn't find any solution.